# What are the key differences between between the Dart Streams API (with rxdart) and other reactive libraries such as RxJava and RxJS?

Tags: stream, dart, flutter, reactive-programming

Right now I'm trying to port the logic of an existing reactive Angular application (RxJS-based) to Flutter. I'm facing a lot of problems with the dart streams API, which seems to behave quite differently than other Rx implementations.

What are the key differences in regards to:

- error and completion events
- `null`/`void` value handling
- stream reusability
- multicast (`publish`, `refcount`, `shareReplay`)
- subscription management

?

Comment: This question is way too broad for StackOverflow. StackOverflow is for concrete programming questions. This question properly answered probably becomes an essay with 30 pages.

Comment: The difference between rxdart and rxjs is written directly on rxdart Readme

Comment: @RémiRousselet I'm unable to find a list of differences or even the word "rxjs" in the README of rxdart

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart#observable

Comment: If you have a specific scenario that's failing and it's not clear why, please consider writing a [MCVE]

Answer (score 6):

From [Rx Observables vs Dart Streams](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart#rx-observables-vs-dart-streams)
:

In many situations, Streams and Observables work the same way. However, if you're used to standard Rx Observables, some features of the Stream api may surprise you. We've included a table below to help folks understand the differences.

Additional information about the following situations can be found by reading the [Rx class documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx-class.html).

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────┐
│                 Situation                  │                                                   Rx Observables                                                    │             Dart Streams              │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┤
│ An error is raised                         │ Observable Terminates with Error                                                                                    │ Error is emitted and Stream continues │
│ Cold Observables                           │ Multiple subscribers can listen to the same cold Observable, each subscription will receive a unique Stream of data │ Single subscriber only                │
│ Hot Observables                            │ Yes                                                                                                                 │ Yes, known as Broadcast Streams       │
│ Is {Publish, Behavior, Replay}Subject hot? │ Yes                                                                                                                 │ Yes                                   │
│ Single/Maybe/Complete ?                    │ Yes                                                                                                                 │ No, uses Dart Future                  │
│ Support back pressure                      │ Yes                                                                                                                 │ Yes                                   │
│ Can emit null?                             │ Yes, except RxJava                                                                                                  │ Yes                                   │
│ Sync by default                            │ Yes                                                                                                                 │ No                                    │
│ Can pause/resume a subscription*?          │ No                                                                                                                  │ Yes                                   │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────┘
```